# ImportError: cannot import name 'data'

Tags: python-3.x, importerror

When I was replicating the examples on one book, I wrote two python files data.py & Env.py under the same dir.

The textbook uses relative path to import the file data.py. But I got an error like this:

```
from . import data
```

got

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'data'
```

What's wrong with it?

I also made a **init**.py file in the same folder but still didn't work

Comment: What does your folder structure (containing the 2 files) look like?

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. The folder just contains some files (related to the example). Nothing else inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as data.py is in the same directory, you can just do `import data`.  You shouldn't need the `from .`